# bip39 checksum python

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, wallet-recovery, python, mnemonic-seed, checksum

Is there any Python package which will allow me to verify if the checksum of a bip39 mnemonic is valid?  For instance, I have a 24-word bip39 mnemonic, and I might have made a mistake for one of the words.  I want to see which words will result in a valid checksum.

I've seen Javascript versions, but nothing in Python

Comment: If this is being done with a significant amount of funds at stake (e.g. your life savings) be careful with what server you enter your mnemonic into. Ideally it should be a "airgapped computer that has no WiFi, Bluetooth, Ethernet or other networking capability"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone/download [this code from Trezor](https://github.com/trezor/python-mnemonic/) (don't forget the word list).

Then check your word-list like this:

```
from mnemonic import Mnemonic

code = "word1 word2 [...] word23 word24"
mnemo = Mnemonic("english")
isValid = mnemo.check(code) # returns a boolean
print('Checksum is valid: ' + str(isValid))
```